# Signal handler is not able to change variable

Tags: python, signals

I'm trying to create a simple signal handler for my Python application but the value of `exiting` does not change even when I use `Ctrl-C`. If I put `exiting`, out of the `main` function the value changes. How can I change the value of `exiting` when it is inside `main()`? Currently, the program always prints
`False` no matter if I press `Ctrl-C` or not.

```py
import signal
import time


def main():
    exiting = False

    def handler(f, b):
        global exiting
        exiting = True
        return

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    while True:
        print(exiting)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What happens if you change `global` to `nonlocal`?  May I suggest you review [python scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and perhaps [an example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example) and see if you still have this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I reviewed and the answer was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` should be included in the `main` function too.

```py
import signal
import time


def main():
    global exiting
    exiting = False

    def handler(f, b):
        global exiting
        exiting = True
        return

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    while True:
        print(exiting)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```